# Nodejs - Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, routes

I can't figure out why this gives the error.

If I remove the db.SendTodo from the code in controller.js it works fine but it seems like it is not working for exports.sendTodo in databaseConnect.js

databaseConnect.js File -

//Code

```
const mongo = require('mongodb');
let db = mongo.MongoClient
const assert = require('assert');
let url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/"
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser= require('body-parser')
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
db.connect(url, function(err, client) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Not Responding " + err);
  }else {
    console.log("Connection Established");
    let database = client.db('todo_app_node');
    let coll = database.collection("todos")

     //Error is here 
     exports.SendTodo = (req, res) => {
      console.log("Whoooo");
      coll.insertOne(body, (err, result) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err)
        console.log('saved to database')
        res.redirect('/')
        next()
      })
    }

    //Show The Result
    coll.find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }else if (result.length) {
        //Responding to the requests
         exports.item = result
      }else {
        console.log("A error occured");
      }
      client.close()
    })
  }
})
```

Router.js

```
const express = require("express")
const router = express.Router()
const bodyParser= require('body-parser')
const controler = require('./controller/controller.js');
const db = require('./controller/databaseConnect.js');


router.get("/", controler.renderPage);
router.post('/send', db.SendTodo)//Error is this line
router.get("/css/index.css", controler.cssFiles);
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `.SendTodo` function needs a bit of work. Put `next` in its argument list, then use it correctly. Try this.

```
exports.SendTodo = (req, res, next) => {   // add next to parameter list
  console.log("Whoooo");
  coll.insertOne(body, (err, result) => {
  if (err) return next(err)                // send your error to next()
    console.log('saved to database')
    return res.redirect('/')               // don't use next() after redirect()
  })
}
```

[Here's documentation on error handling in express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html).

And, when your route handler completes the response to the incoming request, don't call `next()`; you're done.

Comment: Sorry but this does not work and still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

the next() function being called is not in the args. So its throwin out the error.

In router :

---

router.post('/send', db.SendTodo,the_actual_function_to_called_next);

---

In controller: (add next so that its passed along from router)

```
exports.SendTodo = (req, res,next) => {
console.log("Whoooo");
coll.insertOne(body, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    console.log('saved to database')
    res.redirect('/')
    next()
})
```

}